# Как добавить searchbar и другие кнопки в хедер

Tags: html, css, header, login

Привет я новичок в программировании и у меня появилась проблема я не могу добавить к моему хедеру эти 3 кнопки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я очень прошу мне помочь ети 3 кнопки должны быть в правой стороне хедера

мой код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <header class="header">
  <a href="" class="logo">Fresh market</a>
  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#work">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#careers">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Shop</title>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
  }
  
  a {
    color: #000;
  }
  
  /* header */
  
  .header {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  
  .header ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  
  .header li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .header li a:hover,
  .header .menu-btn:hover {
    color:green;
  }

  /* Big coder moment, да я гений просто зеленим залив без хекса */
  
  .header .logo {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:green;
    
  }

  .logo::before {
   
    content:url('imgonline-com-ua-Resize-HhpRdaDieHxuk8.png');
            display: inline-block;
            padding-right: 3px;
            vertical-align: middle;
          }
  
  /* menu */
  
  .header .menu {
    clear: both;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
  }
  
  /* menu icon */
  
  .header .menu-icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding: 28px 20px;
    position: relative;
    user-select: none;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon {
    background: #333;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    position: relative;
    transition: background .2s ease-out;
    width: 18px;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    background: #333;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
    top: 5px;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    top: -5px;
  }
  
  /* menu btn */
  
  .header .menu-btn {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
    max-height: 240px;
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
    background: transparent;
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
    top: 0;
  }
  
  /* 48em = 768px */
  
  @media (min-width: 48em) {
    .header li {
      float: left;
    }
    .header li a {
      padding: 20px 30px;
    }
    .header .menu {
      clear: none;
      float: center;
      max-height: none;
    }
    .header .menu-icon {
      display: none;
    }
  }
```

Comment: а что именно не получилось? вы можете так же добавить внутрь `class="menu"` дополнительные пункты, только добавив там стиль `float: right;`  и html не есть программирование

Comment: @Tiarait я занимался простой разметкой на html и такое на сайте некогда не делал : ( у меня просто опыта не хватает немогли бы вы на основе моего кода добавить такое на страницу если не тяжело ?